# MongoDB: find document with composite _id

Tags: mongodb, composite-primary-key

I have documents in my collection with a composite _id like this:

```
_id:{a:"", b:""}
```

What that I want is to find the document knowing only the value of the field a. Is there some way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can do

```
db.whatever.find({"_id.a":"valueOfa"});
```

Or did I not got the question?